# IntelliJ Idea Ultimate downloads old versions of Spring files when Creating new Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

When I create a New Project in IntelliJ Idea under Spring, IntelliJ downloads 4.3.18. How to download the latest Spring files while creating the New Project ? ( July 26 2019 )

I can create the new Java project, then download the latest Spring dist files online, and then copy the jar files in Project Structure->Libraries.

I expect IntelliJ to download the latest Spring files.
Thanks ありがとう

Answer (score 1):

This option is for the legacy projects, use Spring Initializr instead, either from the IDE or from https://start.spring.io/. IntelliJ IDEA will import the project from Gradle or Maven.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  The Udemy course started as teaching with Legacy, then ended with Spring Initializr.